# How to delete some of the unique records from my excel file with more than 200k number of rows?

Tags: sql, filter, ms-word, excel

I have an excel file with 25 columns with a lot of data, over 200K rows. One of the columns I have has unique data without any duplicates. **Some** of the columns have duplicate values. The column with the unique data has obviously unique records even for the same customer. Is there any way I can **delete** the record from the **unique column** which has **same** value in the **other** columns. I hope this makes sense and someone is able to help.

I will appreciate it.

Input:
id                 Name                   Address            Mobile no. 
123               Ran                      street1            2585658
124               Ran                      street1            2585658
125               Kidfg                     Street4           8585558
126               gffhd                     wert              43646463
127               And                     street8            258455
128               and                      street8            258455

Expected output

id                 Name                   Address            Mobile no. 
123               Ran                      street1            2585658
125               Kidfg                     Street4           8585558
126               gffhd                     wert              43646463
127               And                     street8            258455

Comment: Can you add a sample of inputs and *(matching)* outputs.

Comment: Do you need a solution for excel or for an SQL Statement?

Comment: An SQL statement could be something like `SELECT MIN(id), Name, Address, [Mobile no.] FROM YourTable GROUP BY Name, Address, [Mobile no.]`

Comment: In Excel I would probably use a pivottable with a MIN on id and go from there.

Comment: I need solution for excel. Is it possible to achieve this in excel. Thank you so much

Comment: You should be able to select your data and use `Remove Duplicates` from the `Data` tab. Just unselect the id column and go.

Comment: In that case I won't be able to delete the rows from the column with the unique values, as there are some columns with duplicate values with different Id's.

Comment: You've lost me there. When I add two rows (1, 'Lieven') & (2, 'Lieven') -> Select both rows -> Remove duplicates -> Deselect column A: Only one row is retained. If that's not what you want, I don't understand the question properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [solution](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/filter-for-unique-values-or-remove-duplicate-values-HP010073943.aspx#BMremove_duplicate_values) to your problem on the [office site](http://office.microsoft.com), duplicated below:

> 1. Select the range of cells, or make sure that the active cell is in a table. On the Data tab, in the Data Tools group, click Remove Duplicates.
>
> Do one or more of the following: Under Columns, select one or more
>   columns. To quickly select all columns, click Select All. To quickly
>   clear all columns, click Unselect All. If the range of cells or table
>   contains many columns and you want to only select a few columns, you
>   may find it easier to click Unselect All, and then under Columns,
>   select those columns.
>
> Click OK. A message is displayed indicating how many duplicate values
>   were removed and how many unique values remain, or if no duplicate
>   values were removed.
>
> Click OK.

Comment: I can't remove the duplicates from the other columns. I want to delete the record from the column which has unique data but has duplicate records in other rows. Thank you!